# Setting parameters via BundleExtention class of Symfony rather than using twig global

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

So I am trying to wrap my head around how to set parameters via the `BundleNameExtention` class that resides inside the `DependencyInjection` folder of a bundle rather than defining them directly in `config.yml`

I am using a default `AppBundle` that came with symfony install.

It seems pretty straight forward reading the documentation online that inside the `load` method I should be able to set the parameters I want so this is what I did

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {


        $loader = new Loader\xmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $config['comments'] = "some value";
        $container->setParameter('app.comments', $config['comments']);


    }

    public function getAlias(){
        return 'app';

    }
}
```

How can I access this parameter in my twig template?

Comment: You can pass the parameter from controller, if no then you should make Twig extension. I don't think it's possible to set that parameter in Twig globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this is what I ended up doing to achieve it.

Inside the `DependencyInjection` folder of a bundle along with `AppExtension` class I had to use `Configuration` class as well which implements `ConfigurationInterface` [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html)

My `AppExtension` class

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {    

        $loader = new Loader\xmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter('app.comments', $config['comments']);

    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'app';

    }

}
```

This is my `Configuration` class

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');
        $rootNode->children()->scalarNode('comments')->end();
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And finally inside my `app/config/config.yml`

```
app:
    comments: 'some value'
```

Now to access this simply fetch it via controller and pass it to the twig template.

```
$comments = $this->container->getParameter( 'app.comments' );
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('comments' => $comments));
```

This works for me, hopefully it will help someone else too

Answer (score 1):

You can actually, you'll have to implement the `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;` interface in your extension class, and add the following `prepend` function:

```
class AppExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface{

    // ... your other code 

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container){
        $configs = $container->getExtensionConfig($this->getAlias());
        $config = $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $configs);
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('twig', array(
            'globals' => array('app_comments', $config['comments'])));
    }

}
```

Now you will have access to `app_comments` in all your templates.

Comment: I will check this and get back

Comment: May be I am missing something but this gives me an error of **Notice: Undefined index: comments**